# Regex find comma delimiters not in quotes AND not in parenthesis

Tags: javascript, regex, vbscript, quotes, parentheses

My ultimate goal is to develop a function to convert Access IIF() statements to T-SQL (2008) CASE WHEN statments.  I already have a VBA routine that finds the IIF and the matching closing parenthesis even if it is outside of quotes.  It is recursive and finds nested IIF() statements without using RegEx.  When I narrow down to the text inside the IIF parenthesis I need to identify the two comma delimiters that separate the three parameters.  I am having trouble when a parenthesis is inside of quotes.  How can I setup the RegEx to ignore anything in quotes before processing the rest of the expression?

I'm trying to create an expression group that will find anything inside single quotes and anything inside of parenthesis, then exclude anything that matches that group, and find the commas.  (Please forgive me if I'm not saying this correctly since 'capturing group' and 'non-capturing group' sometimes give me the opposite of what I expect).

Note that this solution has to work with the VBScript Regular Expression support which is basically the same as the JavaScript flavor.

condition, true, false  <-- this is the string my IIF parsing function returns before trying to split into 3 parts.

This is the expression that I've pieced together so far:

```
,(?=([^']*'[^']*')*(?![^']*'))(?![^(]*[)])
```

which works on this:

```
a=1, nz(b,0), Left('xy,z',2)
```

But these lines are more challenging.  I can't find an expression that works on all of them.

```
a=1, '1st)', '(2nd)' 
left(right(a,5),1)='b', '1st)', '(2nd)'
a=1, Left('a,bc',1) , 'xy,z'
```

Here's a Regex101 that I've been working on:

https://regex101.com/r/qH0wD8/2

Comment: The `,(?=([^']*'[^']*')*(?![^']*'))(?![^(]*[)])` is a hacky work around. You need t write a  parser for this.

Comment: I wasn't sure if I was heading down a dark path.  I appreciate the feedback from someone with your reputation.  I ended up writing a parser to convert nested IIF() statements into T-SQL CASE WHEN statements.

Comment: Please post the code here for future visiters.

Comment: I'm happy to share, but where?  A comment only allows 600 characters.  My finished function IIF to CASE conversion function is 10k.  It's written in VBA.

Comment: :) Post as an **answer**, not as a comment. You can answer your own questions.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is, what I was trying to do was not appropriate for RegEx.  Instead I solved the problem by writing a parser that handles nested parenthesis, matching quotes, and miscellaneous commas.

I hope you find this answer because you need a function to **convert IIF() statements to CASE WHEN** and not my complex RegEx inquiry.  The main use case I have for this function is converting Access SQL to T-SQL for SQL Server 2008 and earlier.  SQL Server 2012 and later support the IIF() function.  You can use this VBA function in any VBA editor.  You can use Excel if Access isn't handy.

### Here is a VBA function to convert Access IIF() statements to T-SQL CASE WHEN statments

```
Public Function ReplaceIIFwithCASE(ByVal strInput As String) As String
' Parse the passed string and find the first "IIF(" and parse it into
' a standard T-SQL CASE WHEN statement.  If a nested IIF is found,
' recurse and call this function again.
'
' Ben Sacherich - May 2016-Feb 2017
'
' This supports:
'   IIF() embedded anywhere in the input string.
'   Nested IIF() statements.
'   The input string containing multiple IIF() statements on the same level.
'   Strings between open and close IIF parenthesis that contains literal commas or commas for other functions.
'       Example:  IIF(a=1, nz(b,0) , Left('xy,z',2))
'
' Be aware:
'   This does not optimize the CASE statement in places where a nested IIF could
'     be written as a single CASE statement.
'   It will fail if text inside IIF() containes the pipe character |. If you
'     need to process statements with this character, modify this routine
'     to use another temporary character for |.
'
' Try these in the Immediate window:
'   ? ReplaceIIFwithCASE("IIF(a=1, nz(b,0) , Left('xy,z',2))")
'   ? ReplaceIIFwithCASE("IIf(x='one',IIf(Abs(Z)=1,2,3),'three')")
'   ? ReplaceIIFwithCASE("IIF(a=1,'1st)', '2nd)')")
'   ? ReplaceIIFwithCASE("SELECT Name, IIF(Gender='M', 'Boy', 'Girl') FROM Students")
'
' How this works:
'   Find "IIF(" in the passed string.  Return original string if not found.
'   Search for the matching closing parenthesis.
'   When the match is found, recurse and make sure an "IIF(" is not nested.
'   After recursing, replace the IIF with a CASE statement.
'       - Once I find the inner part of an IIF this will use the Split function
'         to delimit by commas "," into an array.
'       - Then it looks at each array element. If it contains an odd number of
'         single or double quote characters or different number of opening and
'         closing parenthesis, it combines the array element part with the next
'         part and tests again.
'       - When there are matched single/double quotes and equivalent number of
'         parenthesis it holds that part and appends the "|" character.  This
'         means that it has identified one of the 3 parameters that is passed
'         to the IIF function.
'       - Then it splits the string by the "|" character into three pieces
'         and builds the CASE statement.
'   Continue searching the passed string for another occurrence of "IIF(" (not nested).

    Dim lngFuncStart    As Long
    Dim lngPosition     As Long
    Dim intStack        As Integer
    Dim strFunction     As String
    Dim strChar         As String
    Dim strQuoteChar    As String
    Dim bolInQuotes     As Boolean
    Dim strSplit()      As String
    Dim ReturnValue     As String

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    strFunction = "IIF("
    strQuoteChar = "'"      ' Define the style of quotes to look for and exclude.
    bolInQuotes = False     ' We are currently not inside quotes.

    lngFuncStart = InStr(1, strInput, strFunction, vbTextCompare)

    If lngFuncStart > 0 Then
        lngFuncStart = lngFuncStart + Len(strFunction)
        intStack = 1
        lngPosition = lngFuncStart

        Do While lngPosition <= Len(strInput)
        ' Use a WHILE loop instead of a FOR loop because the current and end positions will change inside the loop.

            strChar = Mid(strInput, lngPosition, 1)

            If strChar = strQuoteChar Then
                bolInQuotes = Not bolInQuotes
                ' Move on to the next character

            ElseIf bolInQuotes = False Then
                ' We are currently not inside quotes.

                Select Case strChar
                    Case ")"
                        ' Closing a group
                        intStack = intStack - 1
                    Case "("
                        ' Starting new group
                        intStack = intStack + 1
                End Select

                If intStack = 0 Then ' Found closing parenthesis.

                    ' See if there is a nested match.  ### Recursive ###
                    ReturnValue = ReplaceIIFwithCASE(Mid(strInput, lngFuncStart, lngPosition - lngFuncStart))

                    ' Begin parsing commas.
                    strSplit() = Split(ReturnValue, ",")

                    Dim strPart         As String
                    Dim strRebuilt      As String
                    Dim i               As Integer

                    strRebuilt = ""
                    If UBound(strSplit()) > 2 Then ' There are more than 2 commas.  Piece together the parts.

                        strPart = strSplit(0)
                        For i = 1 To UBound(strSplit)

                            If UBound(Split(strPart, "'")) Mod 2 = 0 _
                              And UBound(Split(strPart, """")) Mod 2 = 0 _
                              And UBound(Split(strPart, "(")) = UBound(Split(strPart, ")")) Then
                                ' Number of single quotes is Even or Zero (matched)
                                ' Number of double quotes is Even or Zero (matched)
                                ' Number of parenthesis is matched

                                ' Add the "|" symbol where the IIF should have commas.
                                strRebuilt = strRebuilt & "|" & strPart
                                strPart = strSplit(i)
                            Else
                                strPart = strPart & "," & strSplit(i)
                            End If
                        Next
                        ReturnValue = Mid(strRebuilt & "|" & strPart, 2)

                        strSplit() = Split(ReturnValue, "|")
                    End If

                    If UBound(strSplit) = 2 Then
                        ' IIF has 3 parameters and is the normal case.
                        '--- Replace the IIF statement with CASE WHEN ---
                        ' CASE statement help:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx
                        ReturnValue = "(CASE WHEN " & Trim(strSplit(0)) & " THEN " & Trim(strSplit(1)) & " ELSE " & Trim(strSplit(2)) & " END)"
                        'ReturnValue = "(CASE WHEN...)"
                        If Right(Mid(strInput, 1, lngFuncStart - Len(strFunction) - 1), 2) = vbCrLf Then
                            ' Don't bother to add a CrLf
                        Else
                            ' Add a CrLf before the CASE statement to make identification easier.
                            ' Comment this out if you don't want it added.
                            ReturnValue = vbCrLf & ReturnValue
                        End If
                        strInput = Mid(strInput, 1, lngFuncStart - Len(strFunction) - 1) & ReturnValue & Mid(strInput, lngPosition + 1)
                    Else
                        ' Something is wrong.  Return the original IIF statement.
                        ' Known issues:
                        '       Text inside IIF() contained pipe character |
                        '       Text contained unmatched parenthesis, maybe inside of a literal string like '1st)'
                        ReturnValue = "IIF(" & ReturnValue & ") /*### Unable to parse IIF() ###*/ "
                        strInput = Mid(strInput, 1, lngFuncStart - Len(strFunction) - 1) & ReturnValue & Mid(strInput, lngPosition + 1)

                    End If

                    '--- Check to see if there is another function call following the one just addressed. ---
                    lngFuncStart = InStr(lngFuncStart + Len(ReturnValue) - Len(strFunction), strInput, strFunction, vbTextCompare)
                    If lngFuncStart > 0 Then
                        ' Another IIF function call is at the same level as the one just processed.
                        lngFuncStart = lngFuncStart + Len(strFunction)
                        intStack = 1
                        lngPosition = lngFuncStart
                    Else
                        ReturnValue = strInput
                        Exit Do
                    End If

                End If
            End If
            lngPosition = lngPosition + 1
        Loop

    Else
        ' Function not found in passed string.
        ReturnValue = strInput
    End If

    ReplaceIIFwithCASE = ReturnValue

    Exit Function

ErrorHandler:

    MsgBox "Error #" & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description & vbCrLf & "in procedure ReplaceIIFwithCASE()" _
        & vbCrLf & "Input:  " & strInput, vbExclamation, "Error"

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursive matching:

```
(?>(?>\([^()]*(?R)?[^()]*\))|(?>'[^']*')|(?>[^()' ,]+))+
```

The outer match is allowed to be repeated `(?>...)+`. Inside, there are three options. The first one matches balanced `()`:

```
(?>\([^()]*(?R)?[^()]*\)
```

The second matches anything between single quotes `'...'`:

```
(?>'[^']*')
```

The third matches anything except `()`, or `'`, or comma, or space:

```
(?>[^()' ,]+)
```